# PlatformIO in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

I downloaded the latest version of VS Code with PlatformIO, i also downloaded the library Mouse.h from PlatformIO Library Manager, and even so, after i upload the code to my Micro Pro the mouse does not respond to the joystick!
But the same code works when i upload via Arduino IDE!

I compared the Mouse.h from .platformio/lib with the Mouse.h from program files\Arduino\libraries
I compared the Mouse.cpp from .platformio/lib with the Mouse.cpp from program files\Arduino\libraries

And they have exactly the same code!

This is my code for my MICRO PRO 32u4 5v:

```c
/* HID Joystick Mouse Example
   by: Jim Lindblom
   date: 1/12/2012
   license: MIT License - Feel free to use this code for any purpose.
   No restrictions. Just keep this license if you go on to use this
   code in your future endeavors! Reuse and share.

   This is very simplistic code that allows you to turn the
   SparkFun Thumb Joystick (http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9032)
   into an HID Mouse. The select button on the joystick is set up
   as the mouse left click.
 */

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Mouse.h>
int horzPin = A0;  // Analog output of horizontal joystick pin
int vertPin = A1;  // Analog output of vertical joystick pin
int selPin = 9;  // select button pin of joystick

int vertZero, horzZero;  // Stores the initial value of each axis, usually around 512
int vertValue, horzValue;  // Stores current analog output of each axis
const int sensitivity = 200;  // Higher sensitivity value = slower mouse, should be <= about 500
int mouseClickFlag = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(horzPin, INPUT);  // Set both analog pins as inputs
  pinMode(vertPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(selPin, INPUT);  // set button select pin as input
  digitalWrite(selPin, HIGH);  // Pull button select pin high
  delay(1000);  // short delay to let outputs settle
  vertZero = analogRead(vertPin);  // get the initial values
  horzZero = analogRead(horzPin);  // Joystick should be in neutral position when reading these
}

void loop()
{
  vertValue = analogRead(vertPin) - vertZero;  // read vertical offset
  horzValue = analogRead(horzPin) - horzZero;  // read horizontal offset
//delay(3000);

  if (vertValue != 0)
    Mouse.move(0, vertValue/sensitivity, 0);  // move mouse on y axis
  if (horzValue != 0)
    Mouse.move((horzValue/sensitivity) *-1, 0, 0);  // move mouse on x axis

  if ((digitalRead(selPin) == 0) && (!mouseClickFlag))  // if the joystick button is pressed
  {
    mouseClickFlag = 1;
    Mouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);  // click the left button down
  }
  else if ((digitalRead(selPin))&&(mouseClickFlag)) // if the joystick button is not pressed
  {
    mouseClickFlag = 0;
    Mouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);  // release the left button
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart VS Code after installing the lib?

For me it fix this kind of problems in some cases.

Edit: Did you "rebuild IntelliSense Index" by press "Ctrl + shift + p"?

Comment: Do you mean a command to restart the services/libraries? Or simply close and opening the VSCode? Because i've done this several times, and my version of VSCode is the last one.
It's sad that not even the PIO developers know how to solve this, and if this same code works in the Arduino IDE, then this case makes the PlatformIO a not reliable extension.

Comment: Simply close VSCode. The reinitialization by reopening solve some times these issues. Sorry I can't help with my work around.